# Timer time does not change as variable?

Tags: android, variables, timer, android-handler

Here is my code,

```
private int V_Time = 1;

.
.
.

try {
final Timer V_Timer;
final Handler V_Handler;
V_Timer = new Timer();
V_Handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
V_Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        V_Handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            webservice_method();
            V_Time = 2; 

            }
        });
    }
}, 0, V_Time * 1000 * 60);
} catch (Exception hata) {

}
```

V_time changes what returns from web service, it seems right in logs altough, it runs every minute. How can set it programmitacally what come form web service?
Ps: I tried  `private long V_Time = 1;` , `private static long V_Time = 1;` etc...

edit:Can I use `cancel()` `run()` etc..? in somewhere?

Comment: how do you check the V_Time value is changed?

Comment: hata.printStackTrace(). Otherwise you risk your app silently crashing without you having any idea why. Anyway, i don't understand your question. What webservice?

Comment: Maybe he wants to change dinamically next  "time in milliseconds between successive task executions" ?

Comment: call webservice every second and get update ui in runonuithread..

Comment: blackbelt is it check every timer run?
eg first timer run 1 minute later, then check it and change v_time and second timer run 2 minutes later?


njzk2 .net webservice call with ksoap2, it is in the timer.
I want just set timer time remote in every timer running...

altaf I do not understand, it calls web service every V_time time, it must be progammitically way to change it?

Comment: still I can not understand what you want to achieve