# Call a method in variable period on everytime?

Tags: android, timer, android-handler

I have to call some webservice method in variable times, every time method runs it returns me next period time as long. I tried it with timer but after first calling, it can not understand new variable time. 
This is the link asked yesterday something about it: [Timer time does not change as variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709439/timer-time-does-not-change-as-variable)

Here is the sample code:

```
private int V_Time = 1;

.
.
.

try {
final Timer V_Timer;
final Handler V_Handler;
V_Timer = new Timer();
V_Handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
V_Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        V_Handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            webservice_method();
            V_Time = 2; // it returns from method, not manually right as shown 
                        //and it can be change every time method calls..

            }
        });
    }
}, 0, V_Time * 1000 * 60);
} catch (Exception hata) {

}
```

It works first time after 1 minute, but others does not change (eg 2 min), it works every 1 minute.

I want just it works properly, with timer or without timer with anything else...
I think I may cancel timer but I guess I cannot resume or restart it again. 
It must be something to do what I want, but I do not to know how?

**I want to change period time, every timer task run what return from method.**

Comment: what's excatly your question

Comment: you want to change the delayed period?

Comment: I know same code with yesterday, I linked too.
Did you see any answer there?
I was trying to change the way, timer is not needed maybe I can use use something else...

Comment: The fact people does not answered you, does not give the right to repost a new question. I still do not understand what do yow want achieve

Comment: In above sample, timer task run first after app start then it runs one minute ago as period time, and it works every one minute. But webservice_method in timer task returns V_time=2 and it must run every 2 minutes altough it still run every one minute.

PS:Sorry about my poor english, I cannot explaint it exactlt I guess.
Is it clear for situation?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is impossible. You have to cancel the current task and reschedule a new one with the new interval.

```
private TimerTask mTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                V_Handler.post(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                       webservice_method();
                       V_Time = 2; // it returns from method, not manually right as shown 
                            //and it can be change every time method calls..
                       V_Timer.cancel();
                        V_Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTask, 0, V_Time * 1000 * 60);

                }
            });

        }
    }

try {
final Timer V_Timer;
final Handler V_Handler;
V_Timer = new Timer();
V_Handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
V_Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTask, 0, V_Time * 1000 * 60);
} catch (Exception hata) {

}
```

Comment: Second task returns me new period, and I guess I cannot use second anymore and first one.

Is there any way to do that, everytime refresh itself?

Comment: you can not refresh. There is no  such way. You have to cancel an reschedule a new one

Comment: I think I cannot new task every period changes, because second one gives me new period time it won't know again.
Can I know a timer is active (not cancelled) and if I use `if` statement, is it work?
if first one cancelled, run second one then flag second one cancelled and work first one again?

I think it seems ipmpossible, but is there any way with timer, handler or alarmmanager etc...

Comment: no it will never work the way you wanto

Comment: Ok, thanks.
you mean no way to do like this?

Comment: no you have to cancel and reschuduel the task everytime